# Problems installing MySQL on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install MySQL in Ubuntu server 22.04.1 whit  but I keep geting this error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-08-17 22:11:24 UTC; 9ms ago
    Process: 1461 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1469 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1469 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
      Error: 22 (Invalid argument)
        CPU: 654ms
Aug 17 22:11:24 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 22:11:24 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 22:11:24 SQL systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
```

After reading this:

[Problems installing MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564215/problems-installing-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (dependency problems)?](https://dpkg:%20error%20processing%20package%20mysql-server%20(dependency%20problems)?https://)

I've tried this:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo apt clean
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

But I'm still getting the same error

Then I read this:

[I did not manage to install mysql on Ubuntu completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224274/i-did-not-manage-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-completely)

So I tried
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`
but then I got this error:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS on a LXC with 4GB of RAM and one CPU core

Edit:

`sudo journalctl -u mysql.service -n 60` outputs:

```
Aug 17 22:24:46 SQL systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 22:24:48 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 27.
```

Comment: look at `journalctl -u mysql.service -n 60`

Comment: ```Aug 17 22:24:46 SQL systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 22:24:47 SQL systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 22:24:48 SQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 27.```

Comment: got this too.. will update if i can figure out a workaround